# Disable *** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated

Tags: ubuntu, security

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and a simple program such as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[ac+1], char **env) {
    char arr[8];

    printf("0x%x\n", av);
    scanf("%s", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

terminates, when attacked with a buffer overrun, with message:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

In previous versions of Ubuntu (or Linux? I don't know what changed), it would print out something like:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
```

Can I restore it? What has changed?

Comment: If you have the old version of Ubuntu still running, executing an strace on the executables and comparing the stderr may give insight

Comment: It might be that they've decided to not have any variables for the print line, since those variables may be suspect as well.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I don't understand your point

Comment: @norake since argv[0] (the program name) lives itself on the stack, the stack smashing detector trying to access the corrupted stack may itself turn into a liability. See the comments from the source code in my answer, and the commit linked from it.

Comment: Yeah - what @norake said. If your stack is smashed, you can't trust it so want to use as little as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not running ubuntu, but I don't think that's possible in newer versions of glibc. See this [commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=ed421fca42fd9b4cab7c66e77894b8dd7ca57ed0).

Short of writing your own stack smashing detector, of course.

You can have a look at the [source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=debug/fortify_fail.c;h=16549d6dbcf5b6e1f808336894c1f4778b88c5bc;hb=1ff1373b3302e9e095dc4fd4d371451c00190780) of the function printing that message:

```c
void
__attribute__ ((noreturn))
__fortify_fail_abort (_Bool need_backtrace, const char *msg)
{
  /* The loop is added only to keep gcc happy.  Don't pass down
     __libc_argv[0] if we aren't doing backtrace since __libc_argv[0]
     may point to the corrupted stack.  */
  while (1)
    __libc_message (need_backtrace ? (do_abort | do_backtrace) : do_abort,
            "*** %s ***: %s terminated\n",
            msg,
            (need_backtrace && __libc_argv[0] != NULL
             ? __libc_argv[0] : "<unknown>"));
}
```

This function will be called with `need_backtrace = False` from the [`__stack_chk_fail`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=debug/stack_chk_fail.c;h=44856555992f72f1411b4fee40878d89119d749c;hb=1ff1373b3302e9e095dc4fd4d371451c00190780), itself called from the stack protector code compiled into the binary.

Comment: This is what I wanted. I remember security exploits against the name of the binary being printed out, do you have any link to them? I could not find any anymore.